# OpenCV in C++ - Calculation of the L Band Power of an Image

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, feature-detection

I have to create a fire-detection program using OpenCV and C++ following an alghoritm from a scientific paper (see image below). At a certain point I have to calculate the "L band power" but I don't know what exacly it means. Can you help me?

[Image of the Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlXfT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it refers the a wavelength of light/EM spectrum.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_band

Edit: Actually I don't think this is correct after reading it again.

Comment: so it's like to say low band?

Comment: Do you have a link to the whole paper?

Comment: You can see the full paper here: [link](http://www.4shared.com/web/preview/pdf/wox7Z_HKba?)